# Acumatica GetLocalizedLabel method sometimes running into key not found

Tags: acumatica

We are running into an 'The Given Key was not present in the dictionary' error while using the ListAttribute.GetLocalizedLabel function to return the text label from our string list. The interesting thing is, the error only happens maybe 1/5 of the time, while it works every other time.

As seen in the attached screenshot, you can see that although the error was thrown in code, the very same code works perfectly fine in the watch window.

[image]

Snippet of the list attribute:

```
public partial class DeliveryStatus
    {

        public class ListAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
        {
            public ListAttribute ()
                : base(
                new string[] { PendingSchedule, Scheduled, Invoiced, Paid, AddressingInProgress, PrintingInProgress, Delivered, AwaitingMailInstructions, Canceled, Stalled, MergeProofInProgress, MergeProofReceived, MergeProofApproval, ReadyToMail, MailingChangesNeeded, PendingDelivery, MergeProofNeedsChanges, PendingSupervisorApproval, PreMailing, PendingXMPieConfig, PendingMergeProofQual, ScheduledWithChanges, PendingXXXing, PreparingShipment, PreparingPickup, PendingRecyle, InvoicedOkToCharge, PendingAutoProcess, PendingEnvelopeAddressing },
                new string[] { PendingScheduleLabel, ScheduledLabel, InvoicedLabel, PaidLabel, AddressingInProgressLabel, PrintingInProgressLabel, DeliveredLabel, AwaitingMailInstructionsLabel, CanceledLabel, StalledLabel, MergeProofInProgressLabel, MergeProofReceivedLabel, MergeProofApprovalLabel, ReadyToMailLabel, MailingChangesNeededLabel, PendingDeliveryLabel, MergeProofNeedsChangesLabel, PendingSupervisorApprovalLabel, PreMailingLabel, PendingXMPieConfigLabel, PendingMergeProofQualLabel, ScheduledWithChangesLabel, PendingXXXingLabel, PreparingShipmentLabel, PreparingPickupLabel, PendingRecyleLabel, InvoicedOkToChargeLabel, PendingAutoProcessLabel, PendingEnvelopeAddressingLabel }) { }
        }
```

Snippet of the DAC field:

```
#region Status        
    [PXDBString]
    [PCMConstants.DeliveryStatus.List()]
    [PXDefault(PCMConstants.DeliveryStatus.PendingSchedule, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public class status : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
```

UPDATE: After working with HB_ACUMATICA I was able to determine that the code we were doing is overkill for our needs. We simply needed to figure out what the text label was for a given key in our string list. We can achieve this without using the cache and such by doing Dictionary labelDic = new PCMConstants.DeliveryStatus.ListAttribute().ValueLabelDic; and then either doing TryGetValue or whatever other method we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug it using the same code GetLocalizedLabel would execute:

```
protected virtual void UsrDeliveryRequest_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row == null) return;

     PXStringListAttribute pxStringListAttribute = sender.GetAttributesReadonly<UsrDeliveryRequest.status>(e.Row).OfType<PXStringListAttribute>().Single();
     string key = (string)sender.GetValue<UsrDeliveryRequest.status>(e.Row);

     if (pxStringListAttribute.ValueLabelDic.ContainsKey(key))
         PXTrace.WriteInformation(PXMessages.LocalizeNoPrefix(pxStringListAttribute.ValueLabelDic[key]));
     else
         PXTrace.WriteInformation("Missing Key, if current UsrDeliveryRequest.Status is valid it should be included in ValueLabelDic.");
}
```

My guess is that when it crashes UsrDeliveryRequest.Status has a value which is not included in:

```
new string[] { PendingSchedule, Scheduled, Invoiced, Paid, AddressingInProgress, PrintingInProgress, Delivered, AwaitingMailInstructions, Canceled, Stalled, MergeProofInProgress, MergeProofReceived, MergeProofApproval, ReadyToMail, MailingChangesNeeded, PendingDelivery, MergeProofNeedsChanges, PendingSupervisorApproval, PreMailing, PendingXMPieConfig, PendingMergeProofQual, ScheduledWithChanges, PendingXXXing, PreparingShipment, PreparingPickup, PendingRecyle, InvoicedOkToCharge, PendingAutoProcess, PendingEnvelopeAddressing }
```

You should avoid fetching the label if the Status value isn't in the allowed key list. Either use SetList to add it to the list or ignore it for special cases such as null.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and the information to help debug it better. It appears that the pxStringListAttribute.ValueLabelDic is returning a count of 0, although the allowed labels has all of them in it. The current key is a value which is 100% in the list attribute. Any other ideas on why the list attribute would come back with no items in the ValueLabelDic? As with the other code, it works most of the time and only breaks after several attempts.One thing to note, that was not outlined in my description is that this function is being called from a long running operation.

Comment: Check allowed values at the place where it's failing: foreach (string value in new PCMConstants.DeliveryStatus.ListAttribute().GetAllowedValues(sender))  PXTrace.WriteInformation(value);

Comment: I would also specify a length for the [PXDBString] attribute as usually all your keys are the same length.

Comment: Also try to follow the Messages pattern for your labels and always reference Label from there: [PXLocalizable(Messages.Prefix)] public static class Messages { public const string Prefix = "Delivery Request"; public const string PendingScheduleLabel = "Pending" etc...}

Comment: Thanks for all of the additional data. After adding the foreach I can see that the .GetAllowedValues returns the 29 values, however the _AllowedValues on the pxStringListAttribute from your original code is returning 0.

Comment: The goal we were trying to achieve was to simply get the label so that we could log it in our history table which we use for reporting. As it turns out, thanks to the code you provided.. all we really needed was Dictionary<string, string> labelDic = new PCMConstants.DeliveryStatus.ListAttribute().ValueLabelDic; so that we could determine what the label was for our given key. Not sure why all of this other code does not work some of the times, but even when the other code failed to find the label, this line worked perfectly.